# Linq query with group by with .NET Core

Tags: list, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a simple query. I want to have a list with a string and a Guid and a sub-list with a decimal and a string. I have my query this way but it keeps getting error when translated to Entity Framework what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
var a = (        from c in DbContext.CC
                 join icc in DbContext.ICC c.Id equals icc.CCId
                 join i in DbContext.I on icc.IId equals i.Id
                 join p in DbContext.P on i.PId equals p.Id
                 select new
                 {
                     GuidId = p.Id,
                     StringN = p.StringN,
                     CCString = c.CCString ,
                     DecimalValue = icc.DecimalValue 
                 }).GroupBy(x => new { x.GuidId , x.StringN }).
                 Select(x => new Model
                 {
                     GuidId = x.Key.GuidId ,
                     StringN = x.Key.StringN , 
                     Values= x.Select(y => new OtherModel
                     {
                         DecimalValue = y.DecimalValue ,
                         CCString = y.CCString 
                     })
                 }
          ).OrderBy(x => x.StringN );
```

Error:

> The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: new {
> GuidId = (p.Id),
> StringN = (p.Name)
> },
> ElementSelector:new {
> GuidId = (ProjectionBindingExpression: GuidId ),
> StringN = (ProjectionBindingExpression: StringN ),
> CCString = (ProjectionBindingExpression: CCString ),
> DecimalValue = (ProjectionBindingExpression: DecimalValue )
> }
> )
> .Select(y => new OtherModel{
> DecimalValue = y.DecimalValue ,
> CCString = y.CCString
> }
> )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: `x.Key` does not have a `CCString` member (hence 2nd select fails). `Model` does not have `StringN` member hence `OrderBy` fails. You say it fails when translated to EF but it should not compile at all. Also you don't say what the error is

Comment: sorry, copy fast.. i have edited my code, it was supposed to be `StringN` instead of `CCString`.

Also, updated the post with the error. Thanks

Comment: Your question still has syntax errors. Please, assert your [mcve] is right

Comment: The error i'm gettng is in the third select that i need to do to get the values. Can i do it other way?

Comment: As @RodrigoRodrigues already said, please provide the entity classes involved within this query and also two or three values within each table and the desired outcome of your query. In that case we could test and debug your problem on our local machine. You can't spot the error while having access to intellisense, debugger and source data. So don't expect anyone can spot the error just by watching your query without knowing the underlying data structure nor has the ability to test or debug it.

Comment: EF Core can translate `GroupBy` **only** if it is followed by `Select` containing **only keys and aggregates**. Your does not fall into that category. See [Complex query operators - GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby) in the official EF Core documentation. The advise is to use `AsEnumerable()` or similar **before** `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is SQL limitation. You cannot select grouped items, only Key and aggregation result is allowed.

Add `AsEnumerable` to your LINQ query to do grouping on the client side:

```cs
var a = (       
    from c in DbContext.CC
    join icc in DbContext.ICC c.Id equals icc.CCId
    join i in DbContext.I on icc.IId equals i.Id
    join p in DbContext.P on i.PId equals p.Id
    select new
    {
        GuidId = p.Id,
        StringN = p.StringN,
        CCString = c.CCString,
        DecimalValue = icc.DecimalValue 
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.GuidId , x.StringN })
    .Select(x => new Model
    {
        GuidId = x.Key.GuidId,
        StringN = x.Key.StringN, 
        Values = x.Select(y => new OtherModel
        {
            DecimalValue = y.DecimalValue,
            CCString = y.CCString 
        })
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.StringN);
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks @Svyatoslav Danyliv